# Apache TomEE 1.7.1 Memory Leak on org.apache.openejb.core.WebContext

Tags: java, primefaces, memory-leaks, apache-tomee, openejb

I'm having a memory leak on my server TomEE. After visiting a page that has a table with more than 100 records and about 20 columns (Nothing too big), the leak appears, after visiting about 100 times (every 5 minutes, 8 hours).

Below, the run parameters of server:

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:+UseParallelGC -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.JspFactoryImpl.USE_POOL=false -Xloggc:gc.log
```

In my production server, each parameter memory is 4 times larger.

I gets a heap dump and found that the object org.apache.openejb.core.WebContext in creatonalContext field, has 78% of the memory. The objects that occupy more space in memory are PrimeFaces and JSF components (See the image).

[Memory consumption of WebContext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7azJi.png)

Now, other additional configurations:

[Settings on web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DM949.png)

Comment: Primefaces 1.0 is not supported anymore

Comment: And please post the web.xml as text here (and fully, not just an irrelevant part) and the image of the memory usage is useless. And if it is a leak, it should appear immediately. Does it result in an OOME? And without an [mcve] that reproduces it, it is very hard to help.

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje for your response. I am preparing an example where you can easily reproduce the error. I did not send all the web.xml because all the other content was not changed.

This error terminates in a OOME. I am using JDK 1.7.0.80, Primefaces 5.2, Apache 1.0.0 deltaspike